# How to remove slashes from couchdb value of a document

Tags: javascript, python, http, python-requests, couchdb

I am trying to send data to couchdb database but I saw that it shows it the couchdb document of the database as this but I sended that data : [image]
like this,  `res = requests.post('http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/captcha_test', json=json.dumps("jL5ZwzE"))` But when I want to see the document where the data is stored, It shows it as :"\"jL5ZwzE\"", I want to remove the slashes. I think it's because I created a view but I don't know.
If someone knows, tell me !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps puts quotation marks around your string, which are than escaped using backslashes. This removes the redundant quotation marks and slashes:

```
json.dumps("jL5ZwzE")[1:-1]
```

You could probably skip json.dumps entirely and just pass "jL5ZwzE" instead.

Comment: It doesn't work, it adds more slashes instead